# Integrate facebook login and fetch user details along with tabbarcontroller in ios6

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

I have implemented facebook login in my app.

1----> I was able to do facebook login but after that logged in user is able to continue with my app i.e a tabbarController with three tab items appears and simultaneously I need to fetch facebook user details (email,firstname,lastname etc)

But I was unable to retrieve details. I do not understand where am I going wrong.

In my ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)performLogin:(id)sender
{
    AppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    SearchViewController *searchViewController=[[SearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];

    UProfile *uprofile=[[UProfile alloc]initWithNibName:@"UProfile" bundle:nil];
    userprofile.title=@"My Profile";

    LogOut *logout=[[LogOut alloc]initWithNibName:@"LogOut" bundle:nil];

    logout.title=@"Sign out";
    tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchViewController,uprofile,logout, nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(sessionStateChanged:)
                                                 name:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

        [FBRequestConnection
         startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                           id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSString *fbUserEmail= @"";

                 NSLog(@"%@",user);

                 fbUserEmail=[user objectForKey:@"email"];

                 AppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

                 appDelegate.fbEmail=fbUserEmail;
             }
         }
         ];
    }
}
```

But here without showing facebook login page I am getting tabbarController and I am unable to retrieve user details.

How can I show facebook login page first and then tabbarController with user details?
After successful login into facebook how can I continue with my app with a tabbarcontroller with first tabitem(corresponding view )selected?

Please help me out in sorting this issue...Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the readPermissions for getting the email for this method, by passing it an `NSArray` with object "email". The remaining information such as name etc is returned by default.

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions
                                allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                           completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
```

of the facebook sdk. If im not mistaken, unless specified permission is "email" then the email object of the user dictionary is `nil`. Modify your state changed handler perhaps to request the user details such as email. Inside the `sessionStateChanged:` handler if session is open u may call a method that simply does this

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", user);
                 NSLog(@"%@", [user objectForKey:@"email"]);

             }
         }];
    }
```